# MPRemoteCommandCenter : UI disappears after I press the pause button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing `MPRemoteCommandCenter` for a radio streaming app. It works as far as the audio will play with the screen locked and the UI appears with the volume control and the pause button is visible.

As soon as I press the pause button the audio stops and the whole audio control UI disappears so that I can not unpause the audio playing by pressing the play button as you would expect.

The method `pauseEvent` gets called on pressing the pause button. See below.

Is anybody able to give me some hints as to where I've gone wrong?

Here is my code:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _streaming = NO;

        _rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

        MPRemoteCommand *pauseCommand = [_rcc pauseCommand];
        [pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
        [pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseEvent)];

        MPRemoteCommand *playCommand = [_rcc playCommand];
        [playCommand setEnabled:YES];
        [playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playEvent)];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) pauseEvent
{
    [_rcc.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
    [_rcc.pauseCommand setEnabled:NO];
    [self.player pause];
    _streaming = NO;
}

-(void) playEvent
{
    [self.player play];
    [_rcc.playCommand setEnabled:NO];
    [_rcc.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
    _streaming = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed this, for some reason, if you did not set any info to `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` that's what happens, just happened to me, i added a random title and now the controls remain on the screen.

This behavior is weird but also understandable, if the remote controls don't have nothing to show, i could think that its ok to dismiss them.

Comment: `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` does not take a title. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe would be consistent with the "pause" method in self.player not returning.  Have you checked for that with a breakpoint?  I don't see any information about self.player, what class is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour. Please check in default music app in iPhone